# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Magnific Popup Gallery + {{ image.path }}

Tags: octobercms

I use for photogallery plugin Cool gallery with RainLab Blog integration https://octobercms.com/plugin/pollozen-simplegallery

In template i link images:

```
{% for image in gallery.images %}
<a href="{{ url('/') }}{{ image.path }}" class="thumb_image"><img src="{{ image.thumb(300,250) }}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
```

{% endfor %}

For JS gallery i USE:

```
        $('#gallery_in_post').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            image: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function(item) {
                    return item.el.children()[0].attributes['title'].value + '<small>' + item.el.children()[0].attributes['alt'].value + '</small>';
                }
            }
        });
```

But when I click on link on big images a get:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Comment: This type of thing should really be followed up with the author of this product. See the support section here: https://octobercms.com/plugin/support/pollozen-simplegallery